# Definite integral involving the spatial part of the Schwarzschild metric

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For real $a>0$, I would like to prove (or disprove) the statement 
$$\int_0^a\frac{\,\,x^2\, dx}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}-1}}=\frac{5}{16}\,\pi\,a^3.$$

(It seems not straight-forwardly computable with Mathematica)

This integral is related to the volume measure of the spatial part of the Schwarzschild metric in general relativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $u = a/x$, so that $\mathrm du = -a/x^2 \, \mathrm dx = -u^2/a \, \mathrm dx$. Your integral becomes
$$ \int_0^a \frac{x^2 \, \mathrm dx}{\sqrt{a/x - 1}} = a^3 \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm du}{u^4\sqrt{u-1}}.  $$
[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(u%5E4*sqrt(u-1))+from+1+to+infty) confirms that the latter integral is $\frac{5\pi}{16}.$